# Unable to create a delete button in Meteor using reactive-table

Tags: javascript, meteor

I building a sortable table in Meteor with Reactive-Table and having trouble getting my delete button to work for removing entries from the table.

Please see my javascript code below:

```
Movies = new Meteor.Collection("movies");
```

if (Meteor.isClient) {

```
Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-movie": function (event) {
        var title = event.target.title.value;
        var year = event.target.year.value;
        var genre = event.target.genre.value;

        Movies.insert({
            title: title,
            year: year,
            genre: genre
        });

        event.target.title.value = "";
        event.target.year.value = "";
        event.target.genre.value = "0";

        return false;
    }
});

Template.moviestable.events({
    "click .deletebtn": function (event) {
        Movies.remove(this._id);
    }
});

  Template.moviestable.helpers({
      movies : function () {
        return Movies.find();
      },

      tableSettings : function () {
        return {
            showFilter: false,
            fields: [
                { key: 'title', label: 'Movie Title' },
                { key: 'year', label: 'Release Year' },
                { key: 'genre', label: 'Genre' },
                { key: 'edit', label: 'Edit', fn: function () { return new Spacebars.SafeString('<button type="button" class="editbtn">Edit</button>') } },
                { key: 'delete', label: 'Delete', fn: function () { return new Spacebars.SafeString('<button type="button" class="deletebtn">Delete</button>') } }
            ]
        }
      }
  });
```

}

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: and whats the error?

Comment: There's no error. Just that the entry isn't deleted from the table.

Comment: console.log(this._id) what returns? try with this. and tell me what you get.
`"click .deletebtn": function (event) {
        console.log("click")
        console.log(this._id)
        Movies.remove(this._id);
    }` if you see the id and the console "click" ddid you have the autopublish package? if no how the allow rules looks?

Comment: console.log(this._id) returns 'undefined'

Comment: well thats why you are not deleting anything, i never use reactive table but is this table inside some helper? where the context of this is on the object collection?

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` to see what the current data context is inside the click event. Can you please post the code of the template `moviestable`? I guess your table supports deletion of multiple rows with checkboxes in front of each row. In that case the checkbox might hold the object ID of the object that is represented by the checkbox. This allows you to fetch all `:checked` checkboxes and remove the corresponding items. Also without the `insecure` package, you need to delete the database object on the server.

Answer (score 2):

In the [reactive tables docs](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table/#using-events), there's an example of how to delete rows from the table. Adapting the example in the docs for your needs, your event should look like this:

```
Template.moviestable.events({
  'click .reactive-table tbody tr': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var objToDelete = this;
    // checks if the actual clicked element has the class `deletebtn `
    if (event.target.className == "deletebtn") {
     Movies.remove(objToDelete._id)
    }
  }
});
```

The problem you are having is that you are trying to find the `_id` property on the button click instead of the row click.

If you do `console.log(this)` on your button click event (as you have it in your question above) you will get something like this `Object {key: "delete", label: "", fieldId: "2", sortOrder: ReactiveVar, sortDirection: ReactiveVar}` which does not contain the property `_id`

It is easier to register the row click, where the row object is the actual document you are trying to delete, and then check if the event's target has the delete class you added.

Comment: Great response.  Note: Apparently that `event.target.className` function returns a single string containing ALL the classes for the button.  Take care if you have multiple classes for your delete button.